# Why did no one call Starfleet to report the Dyson sphere?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the TNG episode "Relics," the *Enterprise* follows a distress beacon from the *Jenolan,* a Federation ship that disappeared around 80 years ago, and finds it crashed on the surface of a Dyson sphere, a technological marvel that, until this moment, was believed to be purely theoretical in nature.  After some investigation not relevant to this question, they discover that the crew of the Jenolan had found it, done some investigating, then lost engines and crash-landed.

The *Enterprise* does some investigation of its own, ends up in some serious trouble, (because of course they do, it's *Star Trek,*) and eventually manages to escape intact, unlike the *Jenolan.*

But I can't help but wonder.  Maybe it's just hindsight after seeing this thing destroy one ship and almost destroy another, but why was it not the first instinct of the crew of *either* ship to take the most elementary of precautions before beginning to poke at the giant space artifact no one's ever seen before and *call it in?*  Open a channel to Starfleet.  "Hey, guess what.  We just found a *Dyson sphere!*  Yes, I'm serious.  Here are our coordinates.  We're going to investigate now.  Bye."

Especially given that 1) the *Jenolan* was en route to a specific destination and now they weren't going to make it on time, and there were surely people who would like to know why, and 2) it's entirely possible that poking at this thing might provoke a hostile response, or at the very least, an unintentionally harmful one.  (cf. the infamous "whale probe" incident of 2286.)

*Starfleet knows this.*  So why isn't "if you run into something big, powerful, and unprecedented, call it in immediately!" the SOP for such situations?  (Obviously the out-of-universe explanation is that if the *Jenolan* had done so, the episode would never have occurred, but this still feels unsatisfying, a minor blot on an otherwise top-grade episode.)

Comment: A facetious answer would be: Because where would be the drama if people in these shows did the sensible thing?  It's kind of like the Away Teams always being comprised of the most senior officers (including the captain), rather than a well trained team dedicated for that specific mission.

Comment: It does make you wonder how the Dyson sphere could have gone unnoticed all that time since the Jenolan was reported missing in the area... presumably there would have been a search for it at the time which should have encountered the sphere. On a science note... the radiant energy from the star can't just disappear into the surfaces and objects on the sphere's interior... after it's done whatever useful work has been accomplished, there must be waste heat which has to be radiated out from the sphere's exterior which would be observable.

Answer (score 7):

### They did, kinda

In the dialogue (voiceover) we hear

> Captain's log, stardate 46125.3. **Starfleet has dispatched two science vessels to study the Dyson Sphere while we proceed to Starbase fifty five.**

<sub>[Source](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/230.htm)</sub>

Now, granted, this *after* they found Scotty etc. but then there was a lot going on (like answering the *Jenolen's* distress signal for the *Enterprise*) or in Scotty's case non-functional engines.

Phoning home might be a little way down on my list, the sphere isn't going anywhere so a survey seems in order before sending up a flare.

Comment: I think the first half of this answer acks up the question rather than answering it, which is why didn't either vessel call it in *before investigating*. The second half is more relevant, but mere speculation

Comment: Granted but then they rarely, if ever, call home before doing *anything*. They are an exploration vessel after all. Plus we don't now that they didn't, off-screen ☺

Comment: Sure, but this seems pretty special. It potentially represents a living space greater than the entire population of the Federation times a gazillion

Comment: I remember reading the novelization of this episode before it actually aired, with the result that the episode felt *extremely* rushed and paired down. I don't recall if the novelization presented a more rational approach, but wouldn't be surprised if it did.

Comment: A quick peruse of the novelisation doesn't help either, it's essentially the same as the show.

Comment: I would personally say that SOP for "chancing across a massive artificial structure of unknown origin, far beyond anything known, created by an unknown civilisation, with unknown intent and unknown threat stance" would definitely be "observe from a great distance, inform Star Fleet ASAP, do not approach" rather than "blindly dive in head first".  After all, its not going anywhere.  Log it, take some photos from a long distance away, inform your highers up.